# Postgres SQL - different results from LIKE query using OR vs ||

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with an integer column. It has 12 records numbered 1000 to 1012. Remember, these are ints.

This query returns, as expected, 12 results:

```
select count(*) from proposals where qd_number::text like '%10%'
```

as does this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "proposals" WHERE (lower(first_name) LIKE '%10%' OR qd_number::text LIKE '%10%' )
```

but this query returns 2 records:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "proposals" WHERE (lower(first_name) || ' ' ||  qd_number::text LIKE '%10%' )
```

which implies using || in concatenated where expressions is not equivalent to using OR. Is that correct or am I missing something else here?

Comment: Where [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html) did you find the claim that `||` was equivalent to `OR`?

Comment: Where in my question did I mention that the manual claimed that?

Comment: "*implies using ||  is not equivalent to using OR..*" sounds very much as if you expect `||` to be an `OR`

Comment: Being new to postgres sql queries, yes I did expect that. However, I never said that the manual claimed it, but now I have it straight from the horses mouth, which I guess is better than the manual. :)

Comment: I assumed you checked the manual before posting this.

Comment: I did and of course I couldn't find any mention of || as an OR operator, because it isn't one as you rightly pointed out. Hence my confusion. So thinking that it was I ask a perfectly valid question to resolve said confusion.

Comment: "Every question is a cry to understand the world. There is no such thing as a dumb question." Carl Sagan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have nulls in `first_name`. For these records `(lower(first_name) || ' ' ||  qd_number::text` results in null, so you don't find the numbers any longer.

Comment: Bingo, that was the reason (on top of me thinking that || was equivalent to OR but now I know it is in fact string concat!)

Answer (score 2):

> using `||` in concatenated where expressions is not equivalent to using `OR`
> Is that correct or am I missing something else here?

That is correct.

`||` is the [string concatenation operator in SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html), not the `OR` operator.